# Unable to redirect my LOGIN page to home page

Tags: php, html

I am facing the problem for my login page. Even after entering correct username and password it is not redirecting to my home page (index.php).

index.php:

```
<?php 
  if (!isset($_SESSION['login_username']))
   {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }

  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) 
  {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['login_username']);
    header("location:login.php");
  }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['success'])): ?>
      <div class="error success"> 
        <h3>
          <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['success'];
            unset ($_SESSION['success']);
          ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION["login_username"])): ?>
  <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['login_username']?></strong></p>
  <p><a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Logout</a></p>
<?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php include('connect.php')?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>ADMIN LOGIN</h2>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="login.php" name ="login">

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>UserName</label>
                    <input type="varchar" required="required" name="login_username">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" required="required" name="login_password" >
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit_login">login</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

connect.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php


$username= "root";
$password = "";

$errors = array();

$db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db1');


if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) 
    {
      $login_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['login_username']);
      $login_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['login_password']);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE login_username='$login_username' AND login_password='$login_password'";

        $result = $db->query($sql);


        if ($result->num_rows == 1) 
        {
          $_SESSION['login_username'] = $login_username;
          $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";

          Header( 'Location: index.php' );
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Wrong username/password combination";
        }
}
</body>
</html>
```

Everything else is working fine , like when Wrong username/password combination is used the msg is displayed but when correct combination is used nothing happens.

Comment: Isn't PHP case sensitive? it should be `header('Location: index.php')`, not `Header('Location: index.php')`

Comment: You are sending outout before calling `header`, that is something you should not do, and which would only work if output buffering was enabled. Please go and make sure that you have proper PHP error reporting enabled first of all, if not the case yet - then PHP will warn you about such mistakes.

Comment: @catcon i tried using both Header('Location: index.php') and header('Location: index.php') and there was no difference in the outout

Comment: @Dharman i will make note of your tips and take them into consideration in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for `$_SESSION["username"]` in index.php, however, in connect.php you are setting `$_SESSION['login_username']`

Change `$_SESSION['login_username']` to `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: did the change at all the places together only.

Comment: Add  session_start(); at the top of index.php   and before  
          $_SESSION['login_username'] = $login_username; in connect.php

Like this:

 if ($result->num_rows == 1) 
        {
         session_start();
          $_SESSION['login_username'] = $login_username;